# What fieldtype of Django model should I choose to store encrypted data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project where the requirement is to store some encrypted data in the database. What is the preferred fieldtype of Django model for storing encrypted data?

I am currently using CharField, however, I am not sure if this is the best approach. Also, should BinaryField be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on ur encryption. if the encription is a password for example django by default uses `CharField`. but `CharField` always needs to have a `max_length` kwarg. so if ur encryption produces a constant length hash use `CharField` if not u can use `TextField`.

Comment: I am encrypting the password and certificate (used for SSH to remote machine). Is CharField a preffered option certificate as well?

Comment: yeah, exactly find out how many length your encryption has and store it as chafield. also TextField is also fine for the certificate

Answer (score 0):

you can use any field from those, `CharField` , `Textfield` 
bit you need to make sure to store the encrypted string and store it ,so you only store the encrypted desired string,
as the Django do in user model app

[image: django-admin]